How can I fix my cors error in ASP.NET Core 8 app?
For several days now, I've been trying to solve a CORS problem I'm having, however I already did a lot of attempts in the Program.cs file to try to solve this but I can't figure this out.
Basically the CORS error only happens on POST methods.
I have this code in Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddCors(builder =>
{
    builder.AddPolicy("AllowAll", options =>
    {
        options.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

In the browser console I see this:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7278/api/Topaz/SetTabletState' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Can anyone help me figure this out?
I already tried to put the domain on the origins but still does not work.
I already tried to define the CORS policy in the controller but still does not work.

May I know how are you sending request? From which endpoint? Does using postman also throws the same error? Depending on the way you are sending request also crucial to have a look.

CORS is about cross origin.  You are sending from example.com to localhost , and CORS will block because that's not the same origin.

After systematic debugging, I conducted a test using XMLHttpRequest as an alternative to AJAX. Interestingly, I discovered that setting the "datatype" parameter to "jsonp" on AJAX effectively resolves the issue at hand. Notably, when employing XMLHttpRequest for making requests, no Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) errors were encountered.
Also, using XMLHttpRequest does not give me any CORS error and works as expected!

This question reminds me that CORS errors can definitely occur because of not only the backend but also the frontend.

I solved this by adding app.UseCors("AllowOrigin") after I build the app and adding the service this way:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

and make sure you have installed the cores form package manager
